# Ajax does not run php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I used similar code like below to show database tables. It was working then but now it's not working. I have tried many other codes but my post file is not called no matter what I do.

```
<div class="loginform-in">
  <h1>User Login</h1>
  <div class="err" id="add_err"></div>
  <fieldset>
    <form action="./" method="post">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label for="name">Username </label>
          <input type="text" size="30"  name="name" id="name" />
        </li>
        <li> 
          <label for="name">Password</label>
          <input type="password" size="30"  name="word" id="word" />
        </li>
        <li> 
          <label></label>
          <button id="login" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="saveBasics();">Login</button>
      </ul>
    </form> 
  </fieldset>
</div>

<script src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="login.js"></script>
```

login.js

```
alert("hi");

$("#login").click(function(){   
  username = $("#name").val();
  password = $("#word").val();

  $.ajax({
    url: "login.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "name=" + username + "&pwd=" + password,
    success: function(html) { 
      aler(html);
      if (html == 'true') {
        window.location = "login.php";
      } else {
        $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
        $("#add_err").html("<img src='images/alert.png' />Wrong username or 
password");
      }
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
      $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
      $("#add_err").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' /> Loading...")
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

login.php

```
<?php
  echo '<script language="javascript">';
  echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
  echo '</script>';
?>
```

My code is not running login.php file and I don't know why. It should show alert when button is clicked but it doesn't.

Note: I just added alert(html); in my java script file and the alert shows

```
    <script language="javascript">alert("message successfully sent")
    </script>true
```

this

Edited: Every body The javascript is working fine (I think) its just that the response I am getting is the literal php page code.

Comment: You check if `html` is equal to `'true'`. That will never happen.

Comment: but any ways it should show the alert that is written in login.php file. It is not even doing that.

Comment: hey echo "true" in login.php and remove all other code

Comment: Check the console to see the response from the AJAX request. At the very least there should be an HTTP response code which you can use to debug

Comment: No, it should not show the alert. You never tell the browser to treat the string that is returned from the request as HTML. It's just a string.

Comment: I added echo "true";
and added alert 
alert(html); java script file and 
<script language="javascript">alert("message successfully sent")</script>true
This is the alert I get

Comment: Also note that `.css(property, value, 'important')` is not a valid use of the `css()` method. It won't be causing an error, but it also won't apply the `!important` flag.

Comment: @MuhammadSaroshTariq you added it, but you were still returning the full HTML so it's was redundant. Ignore that suggestion anyway as it won't get you anywhere. Have you checked the console to see what the exact response from the request is yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st :** your not sending response  `string` like `'html'`  so that your `if statement` will be never `true`

For testing purpose `echo` the `true` in `login.php` like below

```
<?php
    echo 'true';
?>
```

**2nd :**  In success function `alert` the `response` like this

```
success: function(response){ 

         alert(response);

          },
```

Answer (score 0):

Open browsers console (F12) and see what errors are you getting?

Also, there is a Network tab.

If you will filter the XHR in the Network tab - then you will see, if your request is actually addressing the login.php page and you can see what the page has answered (the Response sub-tab).

Usually, I use more convenient way to fire ajax requests:

```
$.post('login.php', {
    name: $('#name').val(),
    pwd: $('#word').val(),
}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    alert(response); 
});
```

Comment: This technically isn't an answer; it's showing the OP how to debug his code and as such should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't alert message from php through ajax. Instead of it you can do following

**login.js**

```
alert("hi");

$("#login").click(function(){   
  username = $("#name").val();
  password = $("#word").val();

  $.ajax({
    url: "login.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "name=" + username + "&pwd=" + password,
    success: function(html) { 
      if (html == 'true') {
        alert("message successfully sent"); //<-----------alert here
        window.location = "login.php";
      } else {
        $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
        $("#add_err").html("<img src='images/alert.png' />Wrong username or 
password");
      }
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
      $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
      $("#add_err").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' /> Loading...")
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
echo "true"; //<---return only true
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved as I just need to understand how response works.

But question is the alert that I tried to show in login.php works in other forms I have implemented but not here.
Why??